# Run Cypress dockerized passing parameters when using multiple commands

Tags: docker, automation, parameters, scripting, cypress

I have a quick question regarding running cypress in a docker container (not a lot of experience with Docker, sorry if it's a dumb question)

Let's say my scripts section goes like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "rmdir /S /Q cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
    "generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test" : "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
  },
```

And my dockerfile entrypoint goes like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","run"]
```

But I need to pass some parameters when I run cypress from the "docker run" command line... Is there a way to pass the parameter (like for example the --spec param with the specfile name to execute) considering that the "test" script has two commands?

Will the parameter I pass apply just for "npm run scripts"? or both commands will receive it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use `entrypoint` your default command (cmd) will be concatenated to it. So a Dockerfile with an entrypoint of `npm run` and default command of (for example) `test` wil simply result in `npm run test` in the container.

If you want to override the default command or the entrypoint, as both is possible, you have to use `docker run [OPTIONS] my-cypress-image npm run test --spec`.

If you want to run the cypress command it would be: `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash my-docker-image cypress run --spec` for example.

Both options will result in running the container shortly untill the tests are finished. You can also choose to keep the container running via `docker run my-docker-image bash` and to run tests via the `docker exec npm run test` command.